# Javascript Function Not Defined on Partial View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view like so:

```
@model Blah.Blah.ThisModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getScript("/Scripts/Pages/ReferralEdit.js");
    initReferralEdit();
</script>

@* blah blah rest of view here *@
```

Then in my ReferralEdit.js external file I have the following:

```
console.log('external loading');

function initReferralEdit() {
    console.log('function is here');
}
```

When loading this as the main route (non-Ajax), this works fine.  When loading through Ajax, upon checking the console on page load I get the following:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: initReferralEdit is not defined
external loading
```

So, I know the file is being loaded, as the first `console.log()` is firing fine, but the function doesn't seem to be available.

Can anyone explain why?  (and, why the error is showing up on Chrome's log before the `external loading` output?)  How do I add these functions so they're 'registered' or 'in the correct scope' or whatever it is I'm missing?

(I've been through hours worth of trying to find out how to load JS on a partial view, and I'm always stuck on these functions not being defined...)

Comment: Because `initReferralEdit();` is called before the script has loaded (ajax is async). Yo make it work, call `initReferralEdit()` in the success callback

Comment: I've been at this too long today...  `$.getScript('/Scripts/Pages/ReferralEdit.js', function () { initReferralEdit(); });`  - that does it.  Turn your comment into an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: TeaCode has already added one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the file is completely loaded before trying to call any method in it. Try something like below:

```
$.getScript( "/Scripts/Pages/ReferralEdit.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
     initReferralEdit();
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    console.log('failed to load script');
});
```

Comment: thanks, got it now.  I'll mark it answered after the wait period is up.